# issue with SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android

i want to store string in memory through sharepreferance but there are some problem raise that could not store in memory can you please let me know how can i solve this?
any permission needed?

**Code::**

```
SavePreferences("MEM1", LanguageSelcted); 
LoadPreferences();
```

**Method::**

```
public void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {
            try {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(key, value.trim());
                editor.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            }

private void LoadPreferences() {
        try {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            LanguageSelection = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
            Log.i(TAG, "LanguageSelection is :>>>" + LanguageSelection);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "LanguageSelection is :>>>" + LanguageSelection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /*
             * textSavedMem1.setText(strSavedMem1);
             * textSavedMem2.setText(strSavedMem2);
             */
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what problems you're running into?

Comment: when i load preferance it getting no value in string...

Comment: is the SavePrefrences method (or LoadPreferences Method for that matter) throwing any exceptions?

Comment: @MikeIsrael no its not raise any kind of error

Comment: how about throwing in a Log.d() of the value.trim before you insert it and make sure it has a value.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: @user1381267 - are you trying to access the preferences in different activities? Save in activity1.. load in activity2? If so look at abbas answer.

Comment: @MikeIsrael i am sure its string

Comment: @dymmeh yes exactly i am doing like that

Comment: @user1381267 that is great if it is a string, but what is its value?  If it is "" then you are getting exactly what you are putting in, you might just be inserting an empty string.

Comment: @user1381267 - look at abbas answer. You cannot store and load a preference using getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE) across different activities. getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE) only loads the preferences for that specific activity. Once you move to another activity you switch to using the preferences for that activity which is why your string ends up empty when you are in the next activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save should be

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs1 = this.getSharedPreferences(
                                "update", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs1.edit();
                        prefsEditor.putString("URL", apkurl);
                        prefsEditor.commit();
```

And get should be

```
SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("update",
                MODE_PRIVATE);
        String key = pref.getString("URL", "");
```

getSharedPreferences will take two arguments.

Comment: This is correct if he is storing the preferences to be used across activities. getPreferences(int mode) that he is using stores the preferences for a specific activity. So if he's trying to access those preferences in a different activity it won't work. This will account for that and get the proper values.

Answer (score 0):

one thing that stands out is this line:

```
LanguageSelection = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
```

should have a reference...

```
LanguageSelection whateverNameYouWant = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
```

or maybe you mean...

```
String LanguageSelection = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
```

Comment: LanguageSelection is likely a member variable in his app.. Just not using the proper Java variable naming practices